# Reference Django URL in HTML Button

Tags: python, html, django, button

I have the following url in my urls.py

```
url(r'^inline-formset/$', 'order.views.addrow', {'form_class': OrderedItemForm}, name='addrow'),
```

Now i would like to reference this url from a form button but i am not getting the syntax right.

This works:

```
<a href="{% url 'addrow' %}">New Line</a>
```

This has the wrong syntax, please assist

```
<input class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="New Line" onclick="location.href="{% url 'addrow' %}""  />
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your specific problem is that you have a conflict with quote types. Use this instead:

```
onclick="location.href='{% url 'customeroverview' %}'"
```

but note that this is not really a good way of doing things. If you just want a link that looks like a button, then have a normal `a href` and use CSS to style it like a button. In Bootstrap, for example, you can use the "btn btn-*" classes on any element to make it look like a button.

Comment: Thanks for adding this: "this is not really a good way of doing things... have a normal a href and use CSS to style it like a button", as someone that's relatively new to web dev i found the explanation really valuable

Comment: How is this working? there is many single quotations in side.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a url specified in urls.py for **"customeroverview"**

something like

url(r'^xxx/$', 'xxx.views.function', name='customeroverview')

Comment: i made an error in the question, customeroverview should be addrow. I edited the question